# why is there no tag "verb construction"?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-request

I'm referring to the post "refer the letter x refer to the letter"

The tags are of the vaguest kind: grammar word-usage sentence-construction phrase-usage. I suggest to remove all these vague tags and replace them with verb-construction. The problem here is not grammar (a very large area). Word-usage is vague as we have a lot of word classes. The poster does not ask about the structure of the sentence, he does not know how the verb to refer can be constructed: to refer sth to sb or to refer to sth.

Comment: The problem with tags being too specific is that they become less helpful to learners using them to search, even though they might be more helpful to the folks answering or subscribing to tags. I have no issues with adding a more specific tag, or trimming some of the general tags from a question,  but I'd hate to see them replaced altogether.

Comment: *Verb construction* has a different meaning already, designating the various combinations into which lexical and auxiliary verbs can enter--what laymen call "tenses". What you are talking about might be better expressed as *verb-complementation*: the various complements which a particular verb can take.